# How to set global javascript varibles by php so the values are not public?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, variables

I have api keys which i don't want to show in public but still i want to assign these as global javascript variable so i can access these in scripts. The api key are stored in database and available via php.

Suppose i have the php variable `$key` which i want to assign to a global javascipt variable. Not what i do is in the head tag use this line of code.

`window.key = <?php echo $key; ?>;`

But that way the api keys are wide open in the head tag. I think you get the idea. Thanks!

**FYI:** I am working in wordpress. So, if there is any wordpress specific solution you are most welcome!

Comment: If it's a JavaScript variable, it's in the open.

Comment: Any secret keys like that should be kept serverside. Do you really need to use JS to carry out the API calls?

Comment: @JohnP: I am doing it via ajax cross domain. You think i should use the api keys with the proxy script with server site?

Comment: I think you should post into your own script and have it take care of the matter via curl or something. This will keep everything nice and hidden.

Comment: @JohnP: Doing it via curl. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to request the key via ajax.

but it will still be visible at runtime. a person using firebug could check the answer of the request and can also display the variable via console.log in the firebug-console.

a javascript variable is always visible for the client.

Comment: So any variable in javascript can be accessible?

Comment: so it is. try to do your api check serverside if possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, since JavaScript is client-side and therefore **always** public.

Answer (score 0):

All javascripts are visible. You dont tell us why you need api key, so i propose following solutions:

1. You can set a temporary api key for the client
2. If a client wants to download a file via api key you can use proxy, written in php, so when client download page http://yoursite/proxy/ its hiddenly download http://somesite/api/api-key/ and returning for client